# Is there any performance pros/cons from returning from void functions

Tags: c++, performance

Consider the two simple functions

```
void foo()
{
   // do stuff
   return;
}

void bar()
{
   // do same stuff as foo()
}
```

where the only difference between them is foo() contains a return statement and bar() will return after "dropping" out of the function (for a lack of better terms). I assume that the return statement just represents a jump in assembly back to the stored address right before the function call. But I am curious to know if there are any performance differences between the two methods, other than the time it takes to type the 7 extra characters :).

Comment: Even the dumbest C++ compiler will produce identical code.

Comment: this is a level of considering to trade code clarity vs performance which isnt good. Write `return;` if you think it makes the code any clearer (and please don't base the decision on typing 7 characters or not typing them)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik But every instruction has a cost, no? So does "return;" not create an instruction or is an identical one created even without it?

Comment: btw if you really care about the difference you need to look at the compilers output. I would not trust anybody but my compiler when I want to know what my compiler does

Comment: Whether there's an explicit return or not, the "instruction" is the same.

Comment: @NullPointer - This is not assembly. You are not typing out instructions, you are describing the behavior of the program to the compiler, which then emits instructions. The behavior is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler will always insert a `RET` *instruction* at the end of a `void` function (assuming it does not end by throwing an exception). An explicit `return;` *statement* here is not needed, and will have no effect.

The generated assembly in your example is identical:

```
foo():
        ret
bar():
        ret
```

([link to godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1Gn6dz))

The explicit `return` from a function is useful to exit the function early. For example:

```
void foo() {

    // do some work ...

    if (/* some condition */)
        return;
    
    // do more work ...

}
```

Answer (score 3):

**No.**

There is an implicit `return` at the end of a function with `void` return type, if you don't type it.

Don't concern yourself with how function calls and returns are implemented; you're currently in the realm of the abstraction that is C++. You're not programming a computer; you're describing a program. Your executable is *not* a one-to-one mapping of source code lines to computer instructions (not even close).

As it happens, there is no real-world performance difference whether you write `return` yourself or let it be implicit. Why would there be? The semantics are identical. *They're the same program.*

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Standard (working draft, 8.7.4 The return statement [[stmt.return]](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return), emphasis mine):

> A function returns to its caller by the `return` statement.
> The [*expr-or-braced-init-list*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.general#nt:expr-or-braced-init-list) of a `return` statement is called its operand. A `return` statement with no operand shall be used only in a function whose return type is *cv* `void`, a [constructor](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.ctor), or a [destructor](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor). A return statement with an operand of type `void` shall be used only in a function whose return type is *cv* `void`.
> [...]
> **Flowing off the end of** a constructor, a destructor, or **a non-coroutine function with a *cv* `void` return type is equivalent to a return with no operand**. Otherwise, flowing off the end of a function other than main or a coroutine ([[dcl.fct.def.coroutine]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.coroutine)) results in undefined behavior.

There's no reason for a standard compliant compiler to generate different assembly codes for the two functions shown in the question, because they are **equivalent**.

So there won't be any perfomance difference, only different readability of the source code (unless you are following some weird code guideline, reviewers may very well ask you *why* a `return` statement is there).